# Installing gerrit plugin in docker container

Tags: docker, gerrit

When running `gerritcodereview/gerrit` docker container. Gerrit is installed within the `/var/gerrit` directoy in the container. But when trying to install plugins by `docker cp` the plugin .jar file, downloaded from https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-its-jira-bazel-stable-2.16/ into the `/var/gerrit/plugins` directory, plugins are not showing up in the list amongst installed plugins. Eventhough I restarted the container.

I ran gerrit with:

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 gerritcodereview/gerrit
```

And Gerrit is accessible via: 
http://localhost:8080/admin/plugins

I also have a list of plugins in the plugins manager, but don't know how to add more plugins to the list, have tried to use gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com url in [httpd]. http://localhost:8080/plugins/plugin-manager/static/index.html

My `gerrit.config` file looks like this:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        serverId = 62b710a2-3947-4e96-a196-6b3fb1f6bc2c
        canonicalWebUrl = http://10033a3fe5b7
[database]
        type = h2
        database = db/ReviewDB
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8080/
        filterClass = com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.ootb.FirstTimeRedirect
        firstTimeRedirectUrl = /login/%23%2F?account_id=1000000
[cache]
        directory = cache
[plugins]
        allowRemoteAdmin = true
[container]
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
        user = gerrit
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
        javaOptions = -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[noteDb "changes"]
        autoMigrate = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that Gerrit runs from `/var/gerrit`, even for your version as that is the version I used before.

Why don't you use docker-compose together with a custom Dockerfile. This way you can easily recreate your image and don't need to worry about adding plugins again after you upgrade your version.

I would suggest that you play around with these scripts and use it for your testing.

This is what my Dockerfile looks like for my previous 2.16 installation:

```
FROM gerritcodereview/gerrit:2.16.8
# Add custom plugins that are not downloaded from the web
COPY ./plugins/* /var/gerrit/plugins/
# Add logo
COPY ./static/* /var/gerrit/static/
ADD https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.16/job/plugin-avatars-gravatar-bazel-master-stable-2.16/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bazel-genfiles/plugins/avatars-gravatar/avatars-gravatar.jar /var/gerrit/plugins/
USER root
# Fix any permissions
RUN chown -R gerrit:gerrit /var/gerrit
USER gerrit
ENV CANONICAL_WEB_URL=https://gerrit.mycompoany.net/r/
```

And below the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  gerrit:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "29418:29418"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - /external/gerrit2.16/etc:/var/gerrit/etc
     - /external/gerrit2.16/git:/var/gerrit/git
     - /external/gerrit2.16/index:/var/gerrit/index
     - /external/gerrit2.16/cache:/var/gerrit/cache
     - /external/gerrit2.16/logs:/var/gerrit/logs
     - /external/gerrit2.16/.ssh:/var/gerrit/.ssh
    #    entrypoint: java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war init --install-all-plugins -d /var/gerrit
    #    entrypoint: java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex -d /var/gerrit
```

Comment: you're right regarding gerrit directory. the current gerrit has some amount of important repos. Not sure if I will lose datas if I upgrade with the new image. Haven't done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out a way that works for me in my use case.

1. copy content of your public key and insert into ssh web browser profile settings: my_gerrit_admin_username
2. Add key to ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

3. from terminal outside container, run:

```
ssh -p 29418 my_gerrit_admin_username@localhost gerrit plugin install -n its-base.jar https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-its-base-bazel-stable-2.16/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bazel-bin/plugins/its-base/its-base.jar
```

4. check web browser that plugin is installed among plugins.